# Problems with mssql-cli instalation

Tags: sql-server, pip

I'm having an issue with mssql-cli installation since yesterday. After installing this tool with

```
pip install mssql-cli
```

as the official *Microsoft* documentation website suggests. But I'm getting this error :

> **Unable to locate package mssql-cli**

Here is the `pip show` output:

Name: mssql-cli
Version: 0.16.0
Summary: CLI for SQL Server Database. With auto-completion and syntax highlighting.
Home-page: https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli
Author: Microsoft Corporation
Author-email: sqlcli@microsoft.com
License: BSD-3
Location: /home/fernando/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: sqlparse, configobj, enum34, applicationinsights, Pygments, humanize, argparse, wheel, prompt-toolkit, cli-helpers, click, future

Also I've tried to install using `apt-get` but it wasn't finding the repositories even after adding the MS key.

Comment: You're probably better off asking about this on the relevant [GitHub](https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli) page. If you're using `apt`, you'll need to add the relevant repository (such as shown here for [16.04](https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/blob/master/doc/installation/linux.md#ubuntu-1604)) first and use an `apt-get update`, before you can install it.

Comment: What OS, distribution? All I had to do each time I tried to install this on Mac OS or Ubuntu was follow the instructions.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04. I've tried apt-get update already.

Comment: Turned out that I've rebooted my pc by chance and when I've tried again it worked! I thought that Ubuntu didn't require any kind of reinitialization so the installations/configurations could be applied.